# How create servers and clients with socket?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I need to build an app where I have four servers running and one client send some packages to these servers, but these servers have to keep running all the time receiving something from the client(sender).
So I create the both classes, client and server:

```
public class Server {

    public Event receive(int port) {

        Evento event = null;
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);

            Socket s = ss.accept();
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);

             evento = (Evento) ois.readObject();

            is.close();
            s.close();
            ss.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return event;
    }
}



public class Client {
    public void send(Event event, int port) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 2002);
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

            oos.writeObject(event);
            oos.close();
            os.close();
            s.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But as I said, I need these servers keep running all the time, if I test once, that's ok, but twice or more, don't.
How could I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard pattern is to create one thread for each connection.  If you use one thread you can only read from one blocking connection.

Comment: A thread to read the blocking connection. It can contain while loop.

Answer (score 0):

just add a do while block around the readObject.
As a break condition you can check whether the message is something like "exit"..

cheers

Comment: That will not solve the question on having multiple servers since the main thread will be waiting for the client so you have a 1:1 server to client. You need to spawn threads to have 4 concurrent servers running and accepting messages from a client.